# Having issues trying to run a standalone Java 6 program which is packaged in a war file and deployed under tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, war

The issue is that when I run it via Eclipse Juno by clicking on it and "Run as Java Application" it works, 
but it needs to be to run in a Linux shell script or at least from the Linux shell.

I need it to append all the jar files from $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib to my classpath.

Here's my code:

```
package com.myapp.client;

public class ClientApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hi Client");
    }
}
```

When I cd into $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/client issue the following command:

```
java -classpath "/home/devuser/DevTools/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/*:." ClientApp
```

I receive this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClientApp (wrong name: com/myapp/client/ClientApp)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ClientApp.  Program will exit
```

When I go to my home dir (/home/devuser) and type this in, it still doesn't work:

```
java -classpath "/home/devuser/DevTools/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/*:." $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com.myapp.ClientApp

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /home/devuser/DevTools/apache-tomcat-7/0/32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/ClientApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .home.devuser.DevTools.apache-tomcat-7.0.32.webapps.myapp.WEB-INF.classes.com.myapp.ClientApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: /home/devuser/DevTools/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com.myapp.ClientApp.  Program will exit.
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this... Would appreciate it if someone could assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your libraries and classes need to be in your classpath, then the next argument is the path to your class.

```
java -cp '.:/path/to/libdir/*:/path/to/myapp.war' com.myapp.client.ClientApp
```

Comment: Magnus, thank you so much! It works! I did have to cd into my $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes dir, though.